# Exception handling in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception

Hi I am new programmer.. presently working on iphone....

I know that in iphone device if an application encounters some error then the iphone OS closes it automatically.

Other exceptions can be handled easily by user like enterance of numbers, check the internet connection ..and many more

My question is why so much exception handling is required?  Because we know the app will close surely...

Is it only to tell user that why the app was closed?

I really need help...
I know it is a stupid type question but....?
Please answer whatever you want....comments will be accepted also(good or bad both)...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is not expected. If users are in your application and then doing something and suddenly, they are forced to quit, they feel frustruated. Telling them about the reason the app is closed has no use. Users will not understand and not care about it.

Apple wants to keep a good User Experience all the time for Apps in their App Store. This is the reason they have a restricted process to see if the App gives good UX or not

Comment: Because Apple doesn't want their users feel bad when users are working with some app and boom, they leave your app

Comment: k...that is obvious developer also wants that user like his app....      thanks for reply ....thanks...